# I can't understand how to set period of PWM signal

Tags: c, msp430, pwm

i would like to create a PWM signal. And i want the frequency to be close to 38 khz. My theoretical calculation for period is 26.3 microseconds. So i choose 26 microseconds. And i can observe my signal.

But i don't understand how my code works properly :)

(My clock frequency is 1MHz so my clock signal is 1 microseconds )

```
if((P1IN & BIT3)!=BIT3)  { // if button is pressed

for(i=0;i<692;i++){   // pwm signal's duration is 9ms
P2OUT^=0x01;       // switch from 1 to 0 or vice versa
__delay_cycles(4);   
}
P2OUT=0x00;
}
```

my calculation is:

i <692,i++,P2OUT^=0x01; //   total 3 cycles

__delay_cycles(4); //total 4 cycles

so 4+3=7. but i'm confused because i think it should be 13 not 7

(here is my signal)
https://e2e.ti.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/166/f0fd36b0_2D00_bebd_2D00_4a31_2D00_b564_2D00_98962cf4749e-_2800_1_2900_.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can not calculate cycles based on C or C++ code. you need to check the assembly file(s) generated during the compilation of the program. Based on your compiler (which you did not mention) you can pass some some compiler parameters/switches to ask the compiler to leave the generated assembly file(s) in place for you to check the generated assembly instructions. but basically the for loop would have a jump instruction which may take 2/3 cycles and you did not calculate that.

I recommend that you later check the number of cycles of each instruction from the micro controller datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code (per your calculations) switches the output every ~7cycles.  and does this 692 times.  For a total of 346 total cycles, however the total pulse ON time is only ~7cycles.  Suggest:

```
if((P1IN & BIT3)!=BIT3)  
{ // if button is pressed
    // start pwm signal
    P2OUT = 0x01;

    for(int i=0; i< (9*1000);i++) // may need to be adjusted   
    {                  // so pwm signal's duration is 9ms
        _delay( 1 ); 
    }

    // stop pwm signal
    P2OUT=0x00;

    // wait for button to be released
    while( P1IN & BIT3)!=BIT3 ){;}
}
```

I'm not familiar with your microcontroller's PWM details,  However, most have an initialization to set how fast the PWM timer counts and its start/termination count and if it repeats and if the output is a square wave or a step up or a step down signal and the percentage of ON .vs.OFF time.

However, the posted code indicates the PWM is only a regular GPIO bit.

The posted code indicates the PWM on percentage is to be 50percent.  Is this what you want?